# How to display "accident alert" on LCD display after timer times out

Tags: c++, arduino, lcd

I'm making a simple program that that runs traffic lights in a loop and has an ultrasonic sensor and a 16x2 LCD. The concept is that if the ultrasonic reads a distance value equal to or below a preset value it is detecting obstruction in an intersection and it starts a timer. When that timer expires, the LCD display's an alert. But if the distance value goes above the preset value while the timer is active it stops. For the traffic light loop I'm using the standard Arduino "delay" function e.g. delay(3000);. The issue I'm having is the once the timer finishes the LCD does not display anything. For the alert timer in the program I'm using a library called millisDelay. This library allows the timer to run without stopping the program.

I have tried using the millisDelay library to run the traffic lights instead of the standard delay function. But that does not work as it puts the traffic lights in a constant loop.

Libraries used:

millisDelay.h and liquidCrystal.h

---

```
#include <millisDelay.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

int red = 22;
int yellow = 23;
int green = 24;
int red2 = 25;
int yellow2 = 26;
int green2 = 27;
const int pingPin = 7; // Trigger Pin of Ultrasonic Sensor
const int echoPin = 6; // Echo Pin of Ultrasonic Sensor
long duration, inches, cm;
millisDelay alertdelay;
millisDelay ledDelay;

const int rs = 36, en = 38, d4 = 40, d5 = 42, d6 = 44, d7 = 46;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellow, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellow2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pingPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600); // Starting Serial Terminal
}

void loop() {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);
  Serial.print(inches);
  Serial.print("in, ");
  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.print("cm");
  Serial.println();
  delay(100);

  if (cm>=11){
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Intersection");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Clear");
  }

  else if (cm<7){
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Intersection");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Clear");
    alertdelay.start(7000);
    Serial.println("delay started");
  }

  if (alertdelay.isFinished()) {
    Serial.println("There is a crash up ahead");
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Crash Up Ahead");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Use Caution");
  }

  delay(1000);
  //'2'refers to intersection number 2
  //green off,red2 on, yellow on for 3 seconds
  digitalWrite(red2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(green, LOW);
  digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH);
  delay(3000);
  // turn off yellow1, then turn red on for 3 seconds
  digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
  digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
  delay(3000);

  //after 3 seconds keep red 1 on and turn red2 off and green2 on,
  //green2 stays on for 15 seconds to let traffic through
  digitalWrite(red2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(green2, HIGH);
  delay(15000);
  //after 15 seconds green2 turns off, yellow 2 turns on
  //yellow2 turns on for 3 seconds,
  digitalWrite(green2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(yellow2, HIGH);
  delay(3000);
  //after 3 seconds, yellow2 turns off, and red 2 turns on
  digitalWrite(yellow2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(red2, HIGH);
  delay(3000);
  //3 seconds after red2 turns on, red 1 turns off and
  //green 1 turns on for 3 seconds
  //red2 stays on
  digitalWrite(red, LOW);
  digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
  delay(14000);
}

long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds) {
  return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the issues with what you are doing.

1) The code that you have written takes 42 seconds to iterate through the loop. So you check if the alertDelay has finished once ever 42 seconds.
2) The second time around the code reaches the back to the start of the loop, you first end up setting the alertDelay again before checking if it is running or is finished, which resets it, as such, your code never reaches the part where it displays the crash.

This is how I would have done things

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

int red = 22;
int yellow = 23;
int green = 24;
int red2 = 25;
int yellow2 = 26;
int green2 = 27;
const int pingPin = 7; // Trigger Pin of Ultrasonic Sensor
const int echoPin = 6; // Echo Pin of Ultrasonic Sensor
long duration, inches, cm;

long alertDisplayTime = millis(), nextLedSwitchTime = millis();
bool displayAlert = false;

int switch_number=-1;

const int rs = 36, en = 38, d4 = 40, d5 = 42, d6 = 44, d7 = 46;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellow, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellow2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pingPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  Serial.begin(9600); // Starting Serial Terminal
  nextLedSwitchTime=1000+millis();
}

void loop() {
  lcd.clear();

  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);
  Serial.print(inches);
  Serial.print("in, ");
  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.print("cm");
  Serial.println();
  delay(100);

  if (cm>=11){
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Intersection");
     lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
     lcd.print("Clear");
    displayAlert=false;
  }

  else if ((cm<7)&&(!displayAlert)){
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Intersection");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Clear");
    alertDisplayTime = millis()+7000;
    displayAlert=true;
    Serial.println("delay started");
  }

  if ((displayAlert==true)&&(alertDisplayTime<millis())) {
    Serial.println("There is a crash up ahead");
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Crash Up Ahead");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Use Caution");
    displayAlert=false;
  }
  if(nextLedSwitchTime>=millis()){
    return;
  }
  long delay_time=0;
  switch_number++;
  switch(switch_number){
    case 0:
  //'2'refers to intersection number 2
  //green off,red2 on, yellow on for 3 seconds
  digitalWrite(red2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(green, LOW);
  digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH);
  delay_time=3000;
  break;
    case 1:
  // turn off yellow1, then turn red on for 3 seconds
  digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
  digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
  delay_time=3000;
  //after 3 seconds keep red 1 on and turn red2 off and green2 on,
  break;
    case 2:
  //green2 stays on for 15 seconds to let traffic through
  digitalWrite(red2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(green2, HIGH);
  //after 15 seconds green2 turns off, yellow 2 turns on
  delay_time=15000;
  break;
    case 3:
  //yellow2 turns on for 3 seconds,
  digitalWrite(green2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(yellow2, HIGH);
  //after 3 seconds, yellow2 turns off, and red 2 turns on
  delay_time=3000;
  break;
    case 4:
  digitalWrite(yellow2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(red2, HIGH);
  //3 seconds after red2 turns on, red 1 turns off and
  delay_time=3000;
  break;
    case 5:
  //green 1 turns on for 3 seconds
  //red2 stays on
  digitalWrite(red, LOW);
  digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
  delay_time = 14000;
    switch_number=-1;
  }
  nextLedSwitchTime = millis()+delay_time;
}

long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds) {
  return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}
```

What this code does is it never blocks the loop funciton, so your pusle in function is carried out almost every second along with the check for the crash.
Also, i have set a bit, which tells the code that the alert delay has already started, which ensures that your code does not reset it.

Comment: Hey Nitro, thanks for your suggestion the code works to loop the sensor perfectly and displays intersection clear before the alert finishes. However, when the alert does finish it does not display "Crash up ahead, use Caution" it displays ("intersectionad clearaution" it mixes up the alert. It also does not reset the display back to "Intersection Clear" once the obstruction is removed.

Comment: Looks like I had kept the LCD.clear function commented out earlier. Try uncommenting it. The coffee should work fine